# Unable to reboot remote machine over ssh

Tags: ssh, root, remote, reboot

I am working with an embedded system and would like to initiate a reboot from a remote machine.

I have tried various methods, including

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${HOST} /bin/systemctl reboot -i
```

but nothing has really worked, the above gives me the following feedback:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start reboot.target: Interactive authentication required.
ee system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
```

and `systemctl status reboot.target` gives me:

```
● reboot.target - Reboot
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

I found that many people have been able to resolve similarreboot issues by prepending sudo to the reboot command but since I'm logging in as `root` already, that should not be needed. I am aware about the security implications that logging in with `root` has but please inore that for now. I would like to focus at the task at hand: How can I trigger a reboot by logging in with root over ssh?

What I've already tried includes:

- `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${HOST} reboot`
- `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${HOST} /sbin/reboot`
- `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${HOST} /bin/systemctl reboot -i`

The remote box runs a custom embedded Linux distribution built with Yocto

Comment: `Interactive authentication required` – I haven't tested, but what if you use `ssh -t …` to give the remote `systemctl` a tty so it's able to interactively ask you the root's password and fulfill the requirement?

Comment: does `sudo reboot` work?

Comment: Give `init 6` a shot aswell

Comment: @Panki, excellent, switching to runlevel 6 solved my problem! Thanks! You can add it as an answer to this question and i'll gladly accept, instead of `init 6`, I did: `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${HOST} /sbin/telinit 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankls to @Panki's comment above, I figured out that  switching to runlevel 6 solved the problem! However, instead of init 6 (as suggested), I did: `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${HOST} /sbin/telinit 6` which did the trick!